# Visualize tag cloud from keyword combinations

Tags: visualization, data-visualization, tagcloud

I have a csv file which contains keyword combinations(e.g consider "apple ipad" as one) in a cell. I want to visualize the csv file in a tag cloud form. Most online ones use only a single keyword to generate the cloud. Is there a desktop or web tool I can use?

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you mean be a keyword combination?

Comment: edited with an example

Comment: So what do you want as output then? If you want to treat "apple ipad" as one tag, just make it "apple-ipad".

Comment: the tagcloud is usually a dynamic visualization. I don't want to change the data I have by modifying it, there can be an intermediate step where that can be done for processing, but the final visualization has to have it separate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Got you.

Try [Wordle](http://www.wordle.net)....

It can handle two-word phrases with the "non-breaking space" character or the tilde character ~ .  Check out the FAQ at http://www.wordle.net/faq#space.

Comment: yep, probably use that as a web-service for sending my csv to http://www.wordle.net/advanced

Comment: It's nicely designed alright.